# Why are my nested root routes being re-mounted when their child routes change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**UPDATE**:

I've found the issue:

The issue isn't exactly with react-router as much as it is with all the examples that are given in terms of using ReactCSSTransitionGroup with react-router. Example: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js

It appears then when the second level child is updated, cloneChildren is called on the parent again but AFTER the url has changed. This causes the key to change and for the parent element to therefore be re-mounted.

Does anybody have any suggestions about how to handle this?

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have the following routes:

```
path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'auth',
      component: LoginLayout,
      indexRoute: {component: SplashView},
      childRoutes: [
        {path: 'login', component: LoginView}
      ]
    }
```

Upon loading my application I would expect the the app to load like this (which it does):

```
<CoreLayout>
  <LoginLayout>
    <Splash />
  </LoginLayout>
</CoreLayout>
```

The line I use to navigate to /auth/login is:

```
browserHistory.push('/auth/login');
```

Now when I attempt to navigate from /auth to /auth/login I am noticing that while CoreLayout does not get unmounted, AuthLayout DOES get unmounted and remounted. Since LoginView is just a child view of AuthLayout, I would have expected both CoreLayout and AuthLayout to only receive componentWillUpdate. Why is AuthLayout being re-mounted?

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md <- This document shows it happening one level deep, but doesn't explain what is supposed to happen when you go two levels deep.

Comment: Just an update as to why I am trying to do this: Initially I only had CoreLayout. Given my login/signup flow and main app layouts are very different, I had a ton of if statements in my CoreLayout, so I decided to split them out into two separate layouts. This worked fine except I am using VelocityTransitionGroup to animate my page changes, and moving from LoginLayout to CoreLayout was not animating. So I made CoreLayout a parent, and created AppLayout. CoreLayouts job is just to wrap it's children in a VelocityTransitionGroup so they when I move from one to the other, they cross fade.

Comment: Looks like the problem came from my use of cloneChildren which is in most examples and used to add a key to your children. Not sure how I am supposed to add a key now, which is affecting some of my transitions.